# In C programming, what is `undefined reference`error, when compiling?

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I have this following simple program I am trying to compile in linux ubuntu.

**`Main.c`**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Person.h"

int main()
{   
    struct Person1 p1 = Person1_Constructor(10, 1000);
}
```

**`Person.c`**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Person.h"

struct Person1 Person1_Constructor(const int age, const int salary)
{
    struct Person1 p;
    p.age = age;
    p.salary = salary;
    return p;
};
```

**`Person.h`**:

```
struct Person1
{
    int age, salary;
};
struct Person1 Person1_Constructor(const int age, const int salary);
```

Why do I get the following **error** ?

```
/tmp/ccCGDJ1k.o: In function `main':
Main.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `Person1_Constructor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using `gcc Main.c -o Main` to compile.

Comment: @Satya uh, why ? I have a `Person.c` and a `Person.h` whats wrong with that ?

Comment: gcc two .c files together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you link the program you need to give both Main.o and Person.o as inputs.

Build usually is done in two steps (1) compilation and (2) linking.
To compile your sources do:

```
$ gcc -c -o Main.o Main.c
$ gcc -c -o Person.o Person.c
```

Or in one line:

```
$ gcc -c Main.c Person.c
```

Then the resulting object files must be linked into a single executable:

```
$ gcc -o Main Main.o Person.o
```

For small projects, of a few compilation units like yours, both step can be done in one `gcc` invocation:

```
$ gcc -o Main Main.c Person.c
```

both files must be given because some symbols in `Person.c` are used by `Main.c`.

For bigger projects, the two step process allows to compile only what changed during the generation of the executable. Usually this is done through a Makefile.

Comment: can you give me the correct way to compile this ? Right now i am using `gcc Main.c -o Main`

Comment: @Shiro `gcc Main.c Person.c -o Main`

Comment: so I have to actually mention every .c file in that single command ? I didn't know about this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably occurring because you're compiling only `Main.c` when you need to be compiling `Main.c` and `Person.c` at the same time. Try compiling it as `gcc Main.c Person.c -o MyProgram`.

Whenever you have multiple files, they all need to be specified when compiling in order to resolve external references, as is the case here. The compiler will spit out object files that will later be linked into an executable. Check out this tutorial on makefiles: [Make File Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) It helps to automate this process.