# Building my own library with unitests complains about undefined reference

Tags: c, makefile

I am building a simple library with some unitest facilities. However, the make complains that there is undefined reference while building the unitest. I have posted all the code and makefile. What is the reason for this?

File hierarchy:

```
/bin
/build
  Makefile
/src
  dbg.h
  ex30.c
  libex30.c  
/tests
  dbg.h
  libex30_tests.c
  minuint.h
  runtests.sh
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a
#SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
#all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests
all: $(TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

#$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) 
#   $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
    VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
BADFUNCS='[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)|stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)'
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep $(BADFUNCS) $(SOURCES) || true
```

In /src dirctory, I have two files ex30.c, libex30.c, and dbg.h

ex30.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dbg.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*lib_function)(const char *data);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;
  check(argc == 4, "USAGE: ex30 libex30.so function data");

  char *lib_file = argv[1];
  char *func_to_run = argv[2];
  char *data = argv[3];

  void *lib = dlopen(lib_file, RTLD_NOW);
  check(lib != NULL, "Failed to open the library %s: %s", lib_file, dlerror());

  lib_function func = dlsym(lib, func_to_run);
  check(func != NULL, "Did not find %s function in the library %s: %s", func_to_run, lib_file, dlerror());

  rc = func(data);
  check(rc == 0, "Function %s return %d for data: %s", func_to_run, rc, data);

  rc = dlclose(lib);
  check(rc == 0, "Failed to close %s", lib_file);

  return 0;

error:
  return 1;
}
```

libex30.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dbg.h"


int print_a_message(const char *msg)
{
    printf("A STRING: %s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}

int uppercase(const char *msg)
{
    int i = 0;
  // BUG: \0 termination problems
  for(i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%c", toupper(msg[i]));
  }

  printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int lowercase(const char *msg)
{
    int i = 0;

  // BUG: \0 termination problems
  for(i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("%c", tolower(msg[i]));
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

int fail_on_purpose(const char *msg)
{
    return 1;
}
```

dbg.h:

```
#ifndef __dbg_h__
#define __dbg_h__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define debug(M, ...)
#else
#define debug(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG %s:%d:%s: " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

#define clean_errno() (errno == 0 ? "None" : strerror(errno))

#define log_err(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define log_warn(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[WARN] (%s:%d: errno: %s) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, clean_errno(), ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define log_info(M, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[INFO] (%s:%d) " M "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define check(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) {log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; goto error;}

#define sentinel(M, ...) {log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; goto error;}

#define check_mem(A) check((A), "Out of memory.")

#define check_debug(A, M, ...) if(!(A)){debug(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; goto error;}

#endif
```

In /tests, I have libex30_tests.c, minunit.h, and dbg.h:

libex30_tests.c:

```
#include "minunit.h"

char *test_dlopen()
{

    return NULL;
}

char *test_functions()
{

    return NULL;
}

char *test_failures()
{

    return NULL;
}

char *test_dlclose()
{

    return NULL;
}

char *all_tests() {
    mu_suite_start();

    mu_run_test(test_dlopen);
    mu_run_test(test_functions);
    mu_run_test(test_failures);
    mu_run_test(test_dlclose);

    return NULL;
}

RUN_TESTS(all_tests);
```

minunit.h

```
#undef NDEBUG
#ifndef _minunit_h
#define _minunit_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "dbg.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#define mu_suite_start() char *message = NULL

#define mu_assert(test, message) if (!(test)) { log_err(message); return message; }
#define mu_run_test(test) debug("\n-----%s", " " #test); \
    message = test(); tests_run++; if (message) return message;

#define RUN_TESTS(name) int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {\
    argc = 1; \
    debug("----- RUNNING: %s", argv[0]);\
    printf("----\nRUNNING: %s\n", argv[0]);\
    char *result = name();\
    if (result != 0) {\
        printf("FAILED: %s\n", result);\
    }\
    else {\
        printf("ALL TESTS PASSED\n");\
    }\
    printf("Tests run: %d\n", tests_run);\
    exit(result != 0);\
}


int tests_run;

#endif
```

runtests.sh:

```
echo "Running unit tests:"

for i in tests/*_tests
do
    if test -f $i
    then
        if $VALGRIND ./$i 2>> tests/tests.log
        then
            echo $i PASS
        else
            echo "ERROR in test $i: here's tests/tests.log"
            echo "------"
            tail tests/tests.log
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

echo ""
```

Here is what I get after make:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a    tests/libex30_tests.c   -o tests/libex30_tests
In file included from tests/libex30_tests.c:1:0:
tests/libex30_tests.c: In function ‘main’:
tests/minunit.h:15:38: warning: parameter ‘argc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
 #define RUN_TESTS(name) int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {\
                                      ^
tests/libex30_tests.c:38:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘RUN_TESTS’
 RUN_TESTS(all_tests);
 ^
/tmp/ccqde9jD.o: In function `main':
/home/rex/rex/projects/programming/c/learn_hard_way/ex30/tests/libex30_tests.c:38: multiple definition of `main'
build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a(ex30.o):/home/rex/rex/projects/programming/c/learn_hard_way/ex30/src/ex30.c:9: first defined here
build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a(ex30.o): In function `main':
ex30.c:(.text.startup+0x85): undefined reference to `dlopen'
ex30.c:(.text.startup+0x9c): undefined reference to `dlsym'
ex30.c:(.text.startup+0x120): undefined reference to `dlclose'
ex30.c:(.text.startup+0x188): undefined reference to `dlerror'
ex30.c:(.text.startup+0x1f0): undefined reference to `dlerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tests/libex30_tests] Error 1
```

Comment: You are not linking against the lib containing `dlopen` et. al.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, could you elaborate on what to change in the Makefile?

Comment: Are you sure the posted files are correct? There's no `runtests.sh` and no `lcthw/list.c` (which isn't needed to build). I downloaded everything. I built it. I ran `libex30_tests` directly and it printed output for test_dlopen, test_functions, test_failures, test_dlclose and then said `ALL TESTS PASSED` and `Tests run: 4`. So, the build isn't completely clean, but it does seem to work [without knowing what the `*.sh` script does]. I also get an empty `build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a`. More info? BTW, there's probably a simpler way than the `RUN_TESTS` CPP macro

Comment: @CraigEstey, sorry about that. I updated. Now you should have everything.

Comment: Sorry to be a nitpicker :-), but still missing `lcthw/list.h` ...

Comment: @CraigEstey, ah, sorry. you got it.

Comment: Same caveat :-), but missing whatever `.c` defines `List_create` et. al. (i.e. I'm getting an undefined reference during link)

Comment: @CraigEstey, that is defined in list.h and list.c. Both are placed in src/lcthw/. Could you elaborate your question? I dont think I understand what you asked. If you are getting the same error, that is good. Can you find a way to fix that?

Comment: Easy. I'm missing `list.c` which is not posted [AFAICT--per my first comment]. But, no rush. It's late here, so I'll have to continue this tomorrow.

Comment: @CraigEstey, you got it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C programming, what is \`undefined reference\`error, when compiling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998485/in-c-programming-what-is-undefined-referenceerror-when-compiling)

Answer (score 2):

Those symbols are exported by `libdl.so`.  Link with `-ldl`.

Comment: Do you mean make this change $(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC $(LIBS)? It gives the same error...

Comment: @elixir Try `tests: LDLIBS += -ldl` if you want to avoid global flags.

Comment: @IvanBaldin, adding the line you suggested right below this line: tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET). Does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should add a rule into your Makefile sg like this:

```
%: %.c ${OTHER_OBJECTS_AND_ARCHIVES}
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LIBS}
```

Comment: Does not work. Given errors like this: tests/list_tests.c:13: undefined reference to `List_create'
/tmp/ccREMNYA.o: In function `test_destroy':

Comment: Of course you have to add the other sources/object-modules/ar-libraries instead of the placeholder `${OTHER_OBJECTS_AND_ARCHIVES}`

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues in your `Makefile`. And, I had to guess a bit about the correct file hierarchy. And, your `list.c` was incomplete

---

The big bug in your `Makefile` was this line which you used to build your tests:

```
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
```

`$(TARGET)` is your library `.a` file. By specifying the command this way, whenever you were building a test you got a command (e.g.):

```
cc -o mytest1 -O2 -g lib.a mytest1.c
```

The problem is that `lib.a` gets scanned for dependencies *before* `mytest1.c` is compiled, so the symbols that `mytest1.c` wants from `lib.a` are *not* known by the linker, so nothing is pulled from the library.

The correct command is:

```
cc -o mytest1 -O2 -g mytest1.c lib.a
```

To specify this correctly in the `Makefile`, see the changes below.

---

I've fixed your `Makefile` and annotated the above bug, along with a few others:

```
# NOTE/BUG: there are issues with _not_ using full path. they _can_ be solved
# without doing this, but this makes things easier
SRC := $(shell pwd)

# NOTE: to just _build_ the tests but _not_ try to run them, specify:
#   RUNTESTS=tests
# on the command line
RUNTESTS ?= runtests

# NOTE: cosmetic change to library name
###LIBNAME = YOUR_LIBRARY
LIBNAME = lcthw

CFLAGS += -g
CFLAGS += -O2
CFLAGS += -Wall

# NOTE: IMO, -Wextra is overkill and causes more problems than it's worth
# what I do is something like this and then do:
#   make CMDLINE_CFLAGS=-Wextra
# on those rare occasions where it might be useful
###CFLAGS += -Wextra
CFLAGS += $(CMDLINE_CFLAGS)

CFLAGS += -I$(SRC) -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)

LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

# library sources and objects
# NOTE/BUG: the wildcard was failing
###SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
SOURCES=$(wildcard lcthw/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

# test sources and objects
TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TEST_OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(TEST_SRC))
TESTS=$(patsubst %.o,%,$(TEST_OBJS))

# library target
TARGET=build/lib$(LIBNAME).a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))
TARGETS += $(TARGET)
# NOTE: comment the following out to _not_ build the shared library -- it's
# _not_ used but will be built now (to use it, change TARGET to SO_TARGET when
# building TESTS)
TARGETS += $(SO_TARGET)

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGETS) $(RUNTESTS)

###dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I$(SRC) -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
# NOTE/BUG: in order to link properly $(TARGET) must be the last part of the
# command
#
# (i.e.) doing CFLAGS += $(TARGET) produced the equivalent of:
#   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET) $@.c
#
# instead of:
#   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $@.c $(TARGET)
#
# the reason the first method failed was because the library was scanned
# _before_ the .c was compiled, so it didn't know to pull any .o files from
# it
#
# the second example _will_ work and is closer to what you originally specified,
# but my personal preference is to always build the .o files:
$(TESTS):
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@.o $@.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $@.o $(TARGET)

# just build the tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: $(TESTS)

# build and run the tests
.PHONY: runtests
runtests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
    VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -rf bin build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f $(TEST_OBJS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
BADFUNCS='[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)|stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)'
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep $(BADFUNCS) $(SOURCES) || true
```

*Reminder:* Due to the way code blocks are posted on SO, the *tabs* in the makefile get converted to spaces. So, when you pull the makefile, you'll need to convert leading whitespace on a line to a single tab. Otherwise, you'll see (e.g.) the dreaded `Makefile:59: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

---

Here's the file hierarchy I ended up with:

```
elixir/ex30.c
elixir/lcthw/list.c
elixir/lcthw/list.h
elixir/libex30.c
elixir/Makefile
elixir/tests/dbg.h
elixir/tests/libex30_tests.c
elixir/tests/list_tests.c
elixir/tests/minunit.h
elixir/tests/runtests.sh
```

The makefile works correctly against that. Note that `elixir` could be (e.g.) `/home/elixir/projects/.../mylib` as the makefile now does a `pwd`

But, if [inadvertently] put things in the wrong place, you can certainly move them, but you may have to adjust the `Makefile` a bit.

---

Also, even though `list.c` was posted, it was incomplete and defined only about half of the functions in `list.h`. This bug was masked by the primary makefile bug. So, I added dummy versions to get a clean build:

```
#include <lcthw/list.h>
//#include <lcthw/dbg.h>

List *List_create()
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(List));
}

void List_destroy(List *list)
{
    LIST_FOREACH(list, first, next, cur) {
        if(cur->prev) {
            free(cur->prev);
        }
    }

    free(list->last);
    free(list);
}

void List_clear(List *list)
{
    LIST_FOREACH(list, first, next, cur) {
        free(cur->value);
    }
}

void List_clear_destroy(List *list)
{
    List_clear(list);
    List_destroy(list);
}

void
List_push(List *list, void *value)
{
}

void *
List_pop(List *list)
{
    return NULL;
}

void
List_unshift(List *list, void *value)
{
}

void *
List_shift(List *list)
{
    return NULL;
}

void *
List_remove(List *list, ListNode *node)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

---

The output I'm getting after the fixes looks something like this:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall  -I/home/myhome/elixir -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -c -o lcthw/list.o lcthw/list.c
ar rcs build/liblcthw.a lcthw/list.o
ranlib build/liblcthw.a
cc -shared -o build/liblcthw.so lcthw/list.o
cc -c -g -O2 -Wall  -I/home/myhome/elixir -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  -o tests/list_tests.o tests/list_tests.c
cc -o tests/list_tests -g -O2 -Wall  -I/home/myhome/elixir -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  tests/list_tests.o build/liblcthw.a
cc -c -g -O2 -Wall  -I/home/myhome/elixir -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  -o tests/libex30_tests.o tests/libex30_tests.c
cc -o tests/libex30_tests -g -O2 -Wall  -I/home/myhome/elixir -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  tests/libex30_tests.o build/liblcthw.a
sh ./tests/runtests.sh
Running unit tests:
----
RUNNING: ./tests/libex30_tests
ALL TESTS PASSED
Tests run: 4
tests/libex30_tests PASS
----
RUNNING: ./tests/list_tests
FAILED: Wrong last value.
Tests run: 2
ERROR in test tests/list_tests: here's tests/tests.log
------
DEBUG tests/libex30_tests.c:32:all_tests:
----- test_failures
DEBUG tests/libex30_tests.c:33:all_tests:
----- test_dlclose
DEBUG tests/list_tests.c:113:main: ----- RUNNING: ./tests/list_tests
DEBUG tests/list_tests.c:103:all_tests:
----- test_create
DEBUG tests/list_tests.c:104:all_tests:
----- test_push_pop
[ERROR] (tests/list_tests.c:32: errno: None) Wrong last value.
Makefile:96: recipe for target 'runtests' failed
make: *** [runtests] Error 1
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I apologize for the mistake. I realize I have mixed the two projects...after updating the third time...I have corrected the mistake and i have given the file hierarchy. Could you take a look at the updated post? It has less files and does not really use the linked list code.

Notice the output. It *did* run the non-list tests successfully. If you fill in the dummy functions in `list.c`, the list tests would also work.

As it is, instead of a subdir of `src` for the `ex30` project, it would be cleaner to use a subdir of `ex30`.

But, what I suspect what you really want [ultimately] is something like:

```
elixir/common/dbg.h
elixir/common/rules.mk

elixir/ex30/ex30.c
elixir/ex30/libex30.c
elixir/ex30/Makefile

elixir/lcthw/list.c
elixir/lcthw/list.h
elixir/lcthw/Makefile

elixir/tests/libex30_tests.c
elixir/tests/list_tests.c
elixir/tests/Makefile
elixir/tests/minunit.h
elixir/tests/runtests.sh
```

Note that the bulk of `Makefile` would be moved to `rules.mk` and each `Makefile` would be just a few lines. And, you can add more projects with a similar sub-hierarchy.

IMO, a possibly cleaner variant is:

```
elixir/common/dbg.h
elixir/common/rules.mk

elixir/ex30/ex30.c
elixir/ex30/libex30.c
elixir/ex30/libex30_tests.c
elixir/ex30/Makefile

elixir/lcthw/list.c
elixir/lcthw/list.h
elixir/lcthw/list_tests.c
elixir/lcthw/Makefile

elixir/tests/Makefile
elixir/tests/minunit.h
elixir/tests/runtests.sh
```

The `src` subdir *could* be added for each project.

Along with `build`. But, what I'd recommend for `build` is a top level directory that has per-project subdirs:

```
elixir/build/ex30/libex30_tests
elixir/build/ex30/libex30_tests.o

elixir/build/lcthw/lcthw.a
elixir/build/lcthw/list.o
elixir/build/lcthw/list_tests.o
elixir/build/lcthw/list_tests
```

This has the advantage that the source tree hierarchy is *not* cluttered with `.o`, `.a` and executables (i.e.) things that get rebuilt. This makes setup for `git` easier because you don't need a per-project `.gitignore` file.

YMMV, but, I've done this for my own stuff in every conceivable organization, and this is the one I've settled on, after much trial and error.

If that is okay with you I can adjust accordingly and repost.

---

To give you a more concrete example of a more powerful `rules.mk` file, here is one I use a lot for SO questions.

**Note:** This is just an example. It can *not* be used by itself because it relies upon several wrapper scripts to operate. Don't try to use or adapt it. The best route for you is to build up your own `rules.mk` from scratch, using your original `Makefile` as a starting point.

```
# rules/rules.mk -- ovrstk rules control
#
# options:
#   GDB -- enable debug symbols
#     0 -- normal
#     1 -- use -O0 and define _USE_GDB_=1
#
#   CLANG -- use clang instead of gcc
#     0 -- use gcc
#     1 -- use clang
#
#   CVERBOSE -- build verbosity
#     0 -- normal
#     1 -- add -v to cc and -Wl,--verbose to ld
#
#   MKVERBOSE -- makefile/rules verbosity
#     0 -- normal
#     1 -- verbose
#
#   M32 -- cross-build to 32 bit mode
#     0 -- native build
#     1 -- build for i386
#
#   BNC -- enable benchmarks
#     0 -- normal mode
#     1 -- enable benchmarks for function enter/exit pairs
#     2 -- add min/max
#
#   XCFLAGS -- extra command line CFLAGS
#   XDFLAGS -- extra command line DFLAGS
#
#   DOT_I -- generate preprocessor output
#   DOT_S -- generate assembler output
#
#   GLIB -- added options for glib
#
# symbols:
#   DFLAGS -- -D options
#   CFLAGS -- compiler options
#
#   PREP -- targets to execute before ALL
#   ALL -- things to build (automatically uses LIBNAME/PGMTGT)
#
#     LIBNAME -- library name to build (e.g. foo.a) -- can be multiple
#     OLIB -- list of .o files to build LIBNAME
#     OLIB-<libname> -- list of .o files to build <libname>
#
#     PGMTGT -- program to build (e.g. fludger) -- can be multiple
#     OLIST -- list of .o files to build PGMTGT
#     OLIST-<pgmname> -- list of .o files to build <pgmname>
#
#   CLEAN -- things to clean (automatically uses a bunch of stuff)
#
#   NOPROTO -- do not generate prototypes
#   FINLINE -- allow gcc to inline functions automatically
#   WNOERROR -- inhibit -Werror
#   WEXTRA -- add -Wextra

ifdef OVRPUB
  ifndef SDIR
    SDIR := $(shell pwd)
    STAIL := $(notdir $(SDIR))
  endif

  ifndef GENTOP
    GENTOP := $(dir $(SDIR))
  endif

  ifndef GENDIR
    GENDIR := $(GENTOP)/$(STAIL)
  endif

  ifndef ODIR
    ODIR := $(GENDIR)
  endif

  NOPROTO := 1
endif

# disable prototype generation
ifdef NOPROTO
  PROTOLST := true
  PROTOGEN := @true
else
  PROTOLST := qproto
  PROTOGEN := @qproto
  PROTOALL := proto
endif

ifndef SDIR
  $(error rules: SDIR not defined)
endif
ifndef ODIR
  $(error rules: ODIR not defined)
endif
ifndef GENDIR
  $(error rules: GENDIR not defined)
endif
ifndef GENTOP
  $(error rules: GENTOP not defined)
endif

ifndef _rules_mk_
_rules_mk_ = 1

  CLEAN += $(LIBNAME) $(PGMTGT)

  ifndef NOPROTO
    CLEAN += *.proto
  endif

  CLEAN += *.a
  CLEAN += *.o
  CLEAN += *.i
  CLEAN += *.dis
  CLEAN += *.lst
  CLEAN += *.TMP

  QPROTO := $(shell $(PROTOLST) -i -l -O$(GENTOP) $(SDIR)/*.c $(CPROTO))
  HDEP += $(QPROTO)

  ###VPATH += $(GENDIR)
  ###VPATH += $(SDIR)

  ifdef INCLUDE_MK
    -include $(INCLUDE_MK)
  endif

  ifdef M32
    CFLAGS += -m32
  endif

  ifdef CVERBOSE
    CFLAGS += -v
  endif

  ifdef MKVERBOSE
    MSG := @echo
  else
    MSG := @true
  endif

  ifdef GSYM
    CFLAGS += -gdwarf-2
  endif

  ifdef GDB
    CFLAGS += -gdwarf-2
    DFLAGS += -D_USE_GDB_
  else
    CFLAGS += -O2
  endif

  ifdef DEBUG
    DFLAGS += -DDEBUG=$(DEBUG)
  endif

  ifndef ZPRT
    DFLAGS += -D_USE_ZPRT_=0
  endif

  ifdef BNC
    DFLAGS += -D_USE_BNC_=$(BNC)
  endif

  ifdef GLIB
    _GLIB = glib-2.0
    DFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(_GLIB))
    STDLIB += $(shell pkg-config --libs $(_GLIB))
  endif

  ifdef CLANG
    CC := clang
    CXX := clang++
  else
    ifdef CPLUS
      ifeq ($(STDLIB),)
        STDLIB += -lstdc++
      endif
    endif
  endif

  # alternate -std
  # NOTE: clang++ does not understand c++17
  ifdef CSTD
    _CSTD := $(CSTD)
    ifdef CLANG
      ifdef CPLUS
        ifeq ($(CSTD),c++17)
          _CSTD := c++1y
        endif
      endif
    endif
    CFLAGS += -std=$(_CSTD)
  endif

  ifdef MPI
    export PATH := /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:$(PATH)
    CC := mpicc
    CXX := mpicxx
  endif

  DFLAGS += -I$(GENTOP)
  DFLAGS += -I$(OVRTOP)
  DFLAGS += -I$(OVRBNC)

  CFLAGS += -Wall
  ifndef WNOERROR
    CFLAGS += -Werror
  endif
  ifdef WEXTRA
    CFLAGS += -Wextra
  endif
  CFLAGS += -Wno-unknown-pragmas
  CFLAGS += -Wempty-body
  CFLAGS += -fno-diagnostics-color

  ifdef DOT_I
    NOLDC := @true
    COPTS += -E -P
    O := i
  endif

  ifdef DOT_S
    NOLDC := @true
    COPTS += -S
    SOPTS += -E -P
    O := s
  endif

  ifndef COPTS
    COPTS += -c
    O := o
  endif

  ifeq ($(O),o)
    ALL += $(LIBNAME) $(PGMTGT)
  else
    ALL += $(addsuffix .$(O),$(basename $(PGMTGT) $(OLIST)))
  endif

  ifndef FINLINE
    # NOTE: we now need this to prevent inlining (enabled at -O2)
    ifndef CLANG
      CFLAGS += -fno-inline-small-functions
    endif

    # NOTE: we now need this to prevent inlining (enabled at -O3)
    CFLAGS += -fno-inline-functions
  endif

  ifdef FIXREG
    ifndef CLANG
      CFLAGS += $(FIXREG)
    endif
  endif

  ifndef F95
    F95 := f95
  endif

  ifndef LDC
    ifdef FTN
      LDC = $(F95)
    endif
  endif

  ifndef LDC
    ifdef CPLUS
      LDC = $(CXX)
    else
      LDC = $(CC)
    endif
  endif

  # FIXME/CAE -- gold wiki page says use -Wl but it seems to have no effect
  ifndef CLANG
    ###LDC += -Wl,-fuse-ld=ld.blah
  endif

  ifdef CVERBOSE
    LDC += -Wl,-verbose=2
  endif

  ifdef LIBLIST
    LIBLIST := $(addprefix $(GENTOP)/,$(LIBLIST))
  endif

  CFLAGS += $(XCFLAGS)
  DFLAGS += $(XDFLAGS)

  CFLAGS += $(DFLAGS)
endif

all: $(PREP) $(PROTOALL) $(ALL)

# C
%.o: %.c $(HDEP)
    $(MSG) %.o %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COPTS) -o $*.$(O) $<

%.i: %.c
    $(MSG) %.i %.c
    cpp $(DFLAGS) -P $< > $*.i

%.s: %.c
    $(MSG) %.s %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $*.s $<

# C++
%.o: %.cpp $(HDEP)
    $(MSG) %.o %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(COPTS) -o $*.$(O) $<

%.i: %.cpp
    $(MSG) %.i %.cpp
    cpp $(DFLAGS) -P $< > $*.i

%.s: %.cpp
    $(MSG) %.s %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $*.s $<

# asm
%.o: %.s $(HDEP)
    $(MSG) %.o %.s
    $(AS) $(AFLAGS) -o $*.$(O) $<

%.o: %.S $(HDEP)
    $(MSG) %.o %.S
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COPTS) $(SOPTS) -o $*.$(O) $<

# fortran
%.o: %.f95 $(HDEP)
    $(MSG) %.o %.f95
    $(F95) -c -o $*.$(O) $<

.SECONDEXPANSION:
###.SUFFIXES:

# build a library (type (2) build)
$(LIBNAME):: $(OLIB) $$(OLIB-$$@)
    $(NOLDC) ar rv $@ $^

# build programs
$(PGMTGT):: $$@.o $(OLIST) $$(OLIST-$$@) $(LIBLIST)
    $(NOLDC) $(LDC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(STDLIB)

.PHONY: proto
proto::
    $(PROTOGEN) -i -v -O$(GENTOP) $(SDIR)/*.c $(CPROTO)

.PHONY: clean
clean::
    rm -f $(CLEAN)

.PHONY: help
help::
    egrep '^#' $(SDIR)/Makefile
```

Here is a per-project `Makefile` that uses it:

```
# fastread/Makefile -- make file for fastread
#
# SO: read line by line in the most efficient way platform specific
# SO: questions/33616284

ifndef _fastread_mk_
_fastread_mk_ = 1

  LIBNAME = fastread
  OLIB += rdgets.o
  OLIB += rdmmap.o
  OLIB += lib.o
  OLIB += node1.o
  OLIB += node2.o

  PGMTGT = xrdfile
  OLIST += rdgets.o
  OLIST += rdmmap.o
  OLIST += lib.o
  OLIST += node1.o
  OLIST += node2.o
  ###LIBLIST = fastread/fastread.a

  HDEP += fastread.h

  DFLAGS += -I$(SDIR)
endif

include $(OVRTOP)/rules/rules.mk
```

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. I realize I have mixed the two projects...after updating the third time...I have corrected the mistake and i have given the file hierarchy. Could you take a look at the updated post? It has less files and does not really use the linked list code.

Comment: Many many thank you. I have learned a great deal from your post. "If that is okay with you I can adjust accordingly and repost."  if I understand you correctly, you meant repost the one with the .o and .a generated in the build dir? Yes, that sounds perfect!

Comment: If you think my modified hierarchy is okay, I can adjust the last version of your `Makefile`, as I posted, splitting off the `rules.mk`. I still have copies of all your files. So, what I would need would be the hierarchy that _you'd_ like to use for the near future for your [multiple] projects. That is, I _don't_ need the `.c` and `.h` files reposted. Also, possibly with some of your reasoning as to why you want the hierarchy one way vs another. I'll comment back if I see any red flags. Or, just trust my judgement ;-)

Comment: It's late here, so I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Is this the final version?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The current version _is_ usable. I've been busy elsewhere. But, when adapting the rules.mk file, I've been trying to come up with a version that does _not_ use `.SECONDEXPANSION:` as that has been problematic for me [i.e. it works _if_ there are wrapper scripts, but would have difficulty without them]. Also, I'm removing some of the options that _only_ pertain to my projects to reduce clutter. So, I haven't forgotten about this, it's just taking a little longer than I had hoped for.